# My whole ceases to be anything

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> My prefix isn’t affirmative
>   My infix is somewhat a ring
>   My postfix isn’t a prime
>   My whole ceases to be anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is

> None

My prefix isn’t affirmative

> No

My infix is somewhat a ring

> The letter "o" is somewhat a ring

My postfix isn’t a prime

> One

My whole ceases to be anything

> None